# Aggregate over time windows in PySpark

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a PySpark dataframe (say `df`) like the following:

```
+-----+-----+----------+-----+
| name| type| timestamp|score|
+-----+-----+----------+-----+
|name1|type1|2012-01-10|   11|
|name1|type1|2012-01-11|   14|
|name1|type1|2012-01-12|    2|
|name1|type3|2012-01-12|    3|
|name1|type3|2012-01-11|   55|
|name1|type1|2012-01-13|   10|
|name1|type2|2012-01-14|   11|
|name1|type2|2012-01-15|   14|
|name2|type2|2012-01-10|    2|
|name2|type2|2012-01-11|    3|
|name2|type2|2012-01-12|   55|
|name2|type1|2012-01-10|   10|
|name2|type1|2012-01-13|   55|
|name2|type1|2012-01-14|   10|
+-----+-----+----------+-----+
```

In the above dataframe, for each `name`, I want to find count how many values of `score` are there within 3 consecutive timestamps. For example, for `name1` I want to be able to detect that there are 5 values of `score` between `2012-01-10` to `2012-01-12`, and 3 values of scores between `2012-01-13` to `2012-01-15` (and so on for `name2`).

In my output dataframe , I would expect to have fewer rows than the ones which were there in `df`. Specifically, I would expect to have ~1/3rd the number of rows since I am aggregating / counting over windows of size=3 . I would still like to have a timestamp column which represents the first entry of the window. I would like the windows to be non-overlapping.

**How can I do this using PySpark?**

This is what I have tried till now:

```
win = W.orderBy("timestamp").partitionBy("name").rowsBetween(0,3)
df_agg = df.groupBy( "timestamp" , F.col("name")  ).agg( F.count( F.col("score") ).over(win) )
```

But, I get the following error when I use the above mentioned technique.

```
 org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: expression '`score`' is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function.
```

You can use the following code snippet to create `df` (the example dataframe).

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window as W

df_Stats = Row("name", "type", "timestamp", "score")

df_stat1 = df_Stats("name1", "type1", "2012-01-10", 11)
df_stat2 = df_Stats("name1", "type1", "2012-01-11", 14)
df_stat3 = df_Stats("name1", "type1", "2012-01-12", 2)
df_stat4 = df_Stats("name1", "type3", "2012-01-12", 3)
df_stat5 = df_Stats("name1", "type3", "2012-01-11", 55)
df_stat6 = df_Stats("name1", "type1", "2012-01-13", 10)
df_stat7 = df_Stats("name1", "type2", "2012-01-14", 11)
df_stat8 = df_Stats("name1", "type2", "2012-01-15", 14)
df_stat9 = df_Stats("name2", "type2", "2012-01-10", 2)
df_stat10 = df_Stats("name2", "type2", "2012-01-11", 3)
df_stat11 = df_Stats("name2", "type2", "2012-01-12", 55)
df_stat12 = df_Stats("name2", "type1", "2012-01-10", 10)
df_stat13 = df_Stats("name2", "type1", "2012-01-13", 55)
df_stat14 = df_Stats("name2", "type1", "2012-01-14", 10)

df_stat_lst = [
    df_stat1,
    df_stat2,
    df_stat3,
    df_stat4,
    df_stat5,
    df_stat6,
    df_stat7,
    df_stat8,
    df_stat9,
    df_stat10,
    df_stat11,
    df_stat12,
    df_stat13,
    df_stat14
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(df_stat_lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following, tell me if it's the expected output:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w = Window.partitionBy("name").orderBy("timestamp").rowsBetween(0, 3)
df_agg = demo_df.withColumn("group_count", F.count("score").over(w))
df_agg.show()

# +-----+-----+----------+-----+-----------+
# | name| type| timestamp|score|group_count|
# +-----+-----+----------+-----+-----------+
# |name1|type1|2012-01-10|   11|          4|
# |name1|type1|2012-01-11|   14|          4|
# |name1|type3|2012-01-11|   55|          4|
# |name1|type1|2012-01-12|    2|          4|
# |name1|type3|2012-01-12|    3|          4|
# |name1|type1|2012-01-13|   10|          3|
# |name1|type2|2012-01-14|   11|          2|
# |name1|type2|2012-01-15|   14|          1|
# |name2|type2|2012-01-10|    2|          4|
# |name2|type1|2012-01-10|   10|          4|
# |name2|type2|2012-01-11|    3|          4|
# |name2|type2|2012-01-12|   55|          3|
# |name2|type1|2012-01-13|   55|          2|
# |name2|type1|2012-01-14|   10|          1|
# +-----+-----+----------+-----+-----------+
```

`partitionBy` is equivalent to `groupBy` for `Window` functions, functionality wise at least.

Comment: @pisall : Thanks for trying an answer. However, in my output dataframe , I would expect to have fewer rows. Specifically, I would expect to have ~1/3rd the number of rows since I am aggregating / counting over windows of size=3 . I would still like to have a timestamp column which represents the first entry of the window. I would like the windows to be non-overlapping.

Comment: @SiddharthSatpathy What you're looking for is [window](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.window) which is different that the one we have defined

Answer (score 0):

One option is create a Dataframe with dates ranges starting from the lower date of your dataframe (maybe 2012-01-10). Make an inner join of your dataframe with this new dataframe in order to get your current data with the date ranges you want and now you could make a group by with name, type and timestamp and aggregate with sum. I think this is the best option. The dataframe you create it's made with date ranges so it will not take too much time.